# LINQ query notation in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, linq, xamarin

Is it possible to use "query notation" in Xamarin Studio, in an Android app? I'm not getting the intellisense, etc. Just doesn't seem to recognise it.
I'd like to write something like:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var q = from c in MyList
        join d in MyOther list on c.Id equals d.OtherId
        ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, does it compile and run? Intellisense is not the same as compiling.

Comment: You can going to get very limited intellisense (if any) in Linq QuerySyntax vs. DotNotation